# C# Can't modify Error.Message String

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have to display a validation message when a user selects a date outside the allowed range. The is the code i have to work with:

```
public ActionResult QuickEdit(int pk, string name, string value)
        {
            var freeOfChargeTime = Db.FreeOfChargeTime.Find(pk);
            freeOfChargeTime.ProjectExtension = freeOfChargeTime.ProjectExtension ?? Db.ProjectExtensions.Find(freeOfChargeTime.ProjectExtensionId);
            if ((name == "StartDate" && DateTime.Parse(value) > freeOfChargeTime.EndDate) || (name == "EndDate" && DateTime.Parse(value) < freeOfChargeTime.StartDate))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("StartDate", "the end date must be after the start date");
            }
            if (name == "NumberOfDays" && double.Parse(value) <= 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("NumberOfDays", "Number of days must be > 0");
            }
            if (name == "StartDate" && DateTime.Parse(value) < freeOfChargeTime.ProjectExtension.StartDate)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("StartDate", "the free of charge period start date must be after the project extension start date");
            }
            if (freeOfChargeTime.ProjectExtension is IPextWithEndDate)
            {
                var poWithEndDate = (IPextWithEndDate)freeOfChargeTime.ProjectExtension;
                if (name == "EndDate" && DateTime.Parse(value) > poWithEndDate.EndDate)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("EndDate", "the free of charge period end date must be before the project extension end date");
                }
            }
            if (freeOfChargeTime.ProjectExtension.StatusId == ProjectExtensionStatus.Cancelled ||
                freeOfChargeTime.ProjectExtension.StatusId == ProjectExtensionStatus.Disabled)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Status", "the project extension is cancelled or disabled");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid) return XEditableUpdate(Db.FreeOfChargeTime, pk, name, value);
            Response.StatusCode = 400;
            var error = new Error { Message = "Error: " + ModelState.Errors() };
            return Json(error.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This displays  ["Error: the free of charge period start date must be after the project extension start date\n"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL5y5.png)

I have tried:

```
@*#1*@
error.Message = error.Message.Split('\\').First();
@*#2*@
error.Message = error.Message.Replace("\\n", " ");
@*#3*@
string validationMessage = error.Message.Split('\\').First();
@*#4*@
string validationMessage = error.Message.Replace("\\n", " ");
@*#5*@
string validationMessage = error.Message;
validationMessage = validationMessage.Split('\\').First();
@*#6*@
string validationMessage = error.Message;
validationMessage = validationMessage.Replace("\\n", " ");
```

I still get the same result. Is there any way to get rid of the "\n", or work around the problem?

Comment: try `validationMessage.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty)`

Comment: You probably see that `\n` in the debugger. That's not two chars (`\ ` + `n`), but a single newline character that is displayed by the debugger as `\n`. So all attempts to remove a `\ ` fail, because there isn't any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validationMessage.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\r", string.Empty);
```

Use this code.

Comment: It works, Thanks :) . Can you explain a bit or point me to some documentation?